# ActionbarSherlock Fragment in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I don't know it's a problem of my application structure or a problem with my code.

I have a tabActivity which extends SherlockFragmentActivity.
This has a ViewPager and a TabsAdapter.
There are two Tabs and one OptionsMenu item ("search").
The two tabs are for entering search parameters. One simple, one detaild. If search is clicked, a search is performed and the results shall be shown.

The content of the tabs are already objects of the type SherlockFragment. So far, this works fine.

At the moment, the search results are a seperate activity. I would like to have them in the viewpager as well. So I converted it to a SherlockActivity. But if I make ("this" is the tabActivity) in the onCreate() Method:

```
FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment ft = Fragment.instantiate(this, searchFragment.class.getName(), null);
if(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.searchresults_content) == null)
{
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.searchresults_content, ft).commit();
}
```

and then:

```
this.mViewPager.addView(ft.getView());
```

but `ft.getView();` returns null. OnCreateView from searchFragment will do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.search_results);
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_results, container, false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new SearchResultsWebViewClient());
//... (load data for webview etc...)
    return mView;
}
```

search_results.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id ="@+id/search_results"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is a support library question, not an ActionBarSherlock question.

Comment: I'm working with SherlockFragments and the support Library from the current ABS. The instructions on the ABS said that I have to get the v4 libraray. But the support library I've downloaded had a mismatch with the included support library in ABS. So I took the support library from ABS into my project. My main question is if it's even possible to launch a fragment when the option (not tab) is clicked and how to handle it with the viewpager. So does my code look right?